# how to specify action url in struts 1

Tags: forms, url, jakarta-ee, struts1, struts-action

the action as specified below is not found

```
<form action="editEvaluation.do"  method="post"  >
 ****
</form>
```

the error is :

```
message Invalid path /situationAdministrative/evaluation/editEvaluation was requested
```

but where i write the url as this /GRH/editEvaluation.do , GRH is the name of my project it works fine

this the action mapping in my struts config :

```
 <action path="/editEvaluation" type="ma.struts.action.situationAdministrative.EditEvaluationAction" />
```

the url of my jsp is //localhost:8080/GRH/situationAdministrative/evaluation/evaluations.jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html:form action="/editEvaluation">
    ...
</html:form>
```

Comment: this works , but form my case , i have a  actionForm , only the action , so it won't work ,

Comment: Err, what? I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: when i use the thag html:form , i got this error , Cannot retrieve definition for form bean null

Comment: Then write an ActionForm for this action, or use `<form action="<c:url value='/editEvaluation.do'/>">`.

Comment: what i want to know is why it not working whith the syntax i used , why it looks for the action , in the same sub-folder where is my jsp

Comment: Then why don't you ask that in your question? You specified a relative path (i.e. not starting with `/` or with `http://`). So the path is relative to the URL of the currently displayed page in the browser. If the address bar in your browser is at the path `/GRH/situationAdministrative/evaluation/something`, then it looks in the current "folder", i.e. at `/GRH/situationAdministrative/evaluation/editEvaluation.do`. Note that you should never have the URL of a JSP in the address bar. That means that you access a view directly, instead of going through a controller.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23785/discussion-between-fatidev-and-jb-nizet)

Comment: @fatiDev Why do you have a Struts action, and a form, without an ActionForm?

Comment: it's not a good practice i think but it's question of coding less , and really , even if it's what must be done , i'm not convinced

Comment: so the solution was to specify the attribute base , with the two lines bellow

Comment: String basePath = request.getScheme()+"://"+request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort()+path+"/";

Comment: <base href="<%=basePath%>">